# blackjack card game php

Tags: php, blackjack

I need to work on an example of BlackJack card game in PHP... I've found some examples and try to build my code based on them, though not successfully yet... At this point I created a class and two functions to build up a deck of 52 cards and then with 'shuffle' choose a random card from it. I am still experimenting but I couldn't echo (or print) this one random card. Your advices would be very much appreciated! Here is my code...

```
<?php
/*This class contains a function that sets an array of
 * 4 suits, 13 faces and return a deck of 52 cards with var_dump
 */
Class Deck {
    public $suits = array ('Spades', 'Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds');
    public $faces = array("A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K");
    public $deck = array();
    public $card;
    public $value=0;


    public function __construct() { 

        //This function will build a simple 52 card deck for me
        foreach($this->suits as $suit) { 
            foreach($this->faces as $face) { 
                //I introduce a local variable $value to hold a score Number of a card

                $value = $face;

                if(!is_numeric($face))  {
                    $value = 10; 
                }

                if($face == 'A') {
                    $value = 11; 
                }

                $this->deck[] = array("suit" => $suit, "face" => $face, "value" => $value); 
            } 
        }// end of a loop in loop

        return $this->randomCard();
    }

    public function randomCard() { 
        shuffle($this->deck);
        $card = array_shift($this->deck);
        //var_dump $this->card;
        return $this->card['face'];
        echo ($this->card['face']);
    }

}//end of the class

$obj = new Deck;
var_dump ($obj->suits);
echo '<br>';
print_r ($obj->faces);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
print_r ($obj->deck);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'Test test';
print_r ($obj->card);
?>
```

Comment: well your echo statement is after your return statement for one - try swapping the order so that you 'echo' (print) before you 'return' (exit) the method

Comment: Have a look at [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

i don't get why `$card` is a member var of your class, since it will change everytime you call `randomCard()` and you only use it as a return value. So remove the `$card` from your class

try this:

```
public function randomCard(){
    if(count($this->deck)==0){
        reloadDeck() // you need a funtction which 'reloads' the deck because array_shift will remove the first element
    }

    shuffle($this->deck);
    return array_shift($this->deck);
}
```

return the hole card array because you will need all the information of the card not just the `['face']` value